# ESP8266 chips using different encryption for softAP

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I've got this curious case which I'm trying to make sense of. I use ESP8266 boards in a particular project of mine. There are smaller boards and larger boards, with other modules on them, purchased from different vendors. I don't think this plays much of a role, but fyi.

Now, the project itself involves the usage of ESP's softAP capabilities. A PC app of mine is built to connect and interact with the ESP when it is in softAP mode. I use the ESP8266 Arduino core on both board types, and I *assume* that the underlying Espressif SDK used is also the same. However, when I launch softAP on one board type, it uses AES encryption, whereas the other board type uses TKIP encryption. I know this because I have connected to both via Windows and then taken a peek at their Wi-Fi profiles. Sure enough, the ESP chip on one uses AES, while the other uses TKIP.

What I'm trying to determine is:

1. What determines what encryption the chip uses?
2. Is there a way to switch the encryption used?
   The Arduino core guys have said that they do not cover that in their core ([here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/7825)) and consulting the non-OS docs doesn't really provide any means of manipulating this. Section 3.5 mentions that AES is supported in softAP mode, and also states that "for the group key, only TKIP is supported" (docs [here](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/2c-esp8266_non_os_sdk_api_reference_en.pdf)). I am not sure what this latter part means, if anyone could please clarify, but it doesn't seem like a concern seeing how one of my board types creates AES-encrypted connections, no problem. The only thing that one can provide when opening softAP is the authMode, which is simply a choice between WEP, WPA, WPA2, etc. Looking at the Arduino Core code, WPA2 is used. However, there is no obvious function/struct argument that manipulates the encryption used...

What options are there to change the behavior of the TKIP boards and force them to use AES when setting up a soft AP? Any suggestions or pointers (pun not intended) would be greatly appreciated!

Edit 1:

A day of tinkering later has allowed me to narrow the problem down. I am now using only **one board**. However, **compiling and uploading different projects with identical configurations and Arduino core still causes different encryption types to be used by the softAP**. Briefly, there are 2 projects:

1. My main project which is too large to post here. It activates softAP when I press a physical button.
2. A simple sketch that immediately turns on softAP and just loops without doing anything other than delay()-ing for several seconds to allow ESP to do its thing (see snippet below).

```
    #include <Arduino.h>
    #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
    void setup()
    {
        unsigned long softApFlag = 0;
        IPAddress localIP(0x0201A8C0), gatewayIP(0x0101A8C0), subnet(0x00FFFFFF);
        Serial.begin(115200);
        delay(10000);
        Serial.printf("\nBEGIN***************");
        if ((WiFi.softAPConfig(localIP, gatewayIP, subnet)) == true) {
            softApFlag = 1;
            if ((WiFi.softAP((char*)"Big_SoftAP_Test", (char*)"1234567890")) == true)
            {
                softApFlag = 2;
            }
        }
    Mloop:
        printf("softAP flag = %d\x0d\x0a", softApFlag);
        delay(3000);
        goto Mloop;
        return;
    }
    void loop(){
    }
```

3 scenarios have been observed:

1. My large project in its "natural" state causes softAP to use TKIP.
2. The test sketch always uses AES in softAP mode.
3. If I take the code from sketch 2, paste it at the very beginning of the large project and prevent the rest of the large project code from executing (I don't comment it out or remove it, but loop without doing anything as in the sketch), then I see 2 things.
   -- At first, I could not connect to the softAP from Windows. At all. A quick look at the Windows Event Viewer WLAN-AutoConfig records show it attempting to connect using AES, then using TKIP, but ultimately failing. Is there a 3rd encryption algorithm that's possible? Idk.
   -- After this, by removing excess bits of the large project that had accumulated over the past months, I managed to connect to this version's softAP via AES. I thought I'd cracked it, but removing the small sketch code and restoring the logic of the large project did not, however, retain this behavior, and the softAP started to use either TKIP, or stay unreachable once again...

It really is a messy case and my descriptions probably make little sense, but that's the long and the short of it.

Edit 2:

The problem still persists, but a couple of additional observations: on rare occasions, I do manage to connect to the softAP, if the Event Viewer is to be trusted. This only lasts a few seconds before the PC automatically disconnects.

Also, for some reason, my Android smartphone is much more reliable at locating the network and staying connected to it...

Comment: was the SoftAP configured with the same version of ESP32 Arduino core? (The settings can be persistent)). https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/commit/aec2635b07db3e6bc1792c64b3d60c49ec44bfc2

Comment: the encryption setting is not available in Arduino API. https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/cf43d174b7f64c20bb3499c82739b7240742df8b/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiAP.cpp#L105

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes, I use the exact some Arduino core for both boards (ESP8266 Arduino core 3.1.2), so there shouldn't be any software difference. And yes, the encryption setting is not available in the Arduino API (although you seem to imply that I am using ESP32, which is not the case...). What interests me is... where CAN the encryption be changed anyway? Nothing in the Espressif docs seems to say that it can... But it must be modifiable, surely!?

Comment: sorry, search for occurrences of `softap_config` in https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/2c-esp8266_non_os_sdk_api_reference_en.pdf

Comment: Juraj, I have done a search of all places which utilize the softap_config struct, but this hardly helps. Firstly, I don't have the non-OS source to see how functions actually use this struct, and secondly, the struct itself doesn't really have anything encryption-related (other than the authmode field). The Arduino core sets the authmode field to WPA2 when turning on softAP mode, so there's nothing else that's suspicious here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a short while, it seems like the most satisfying conclusion that I could come up with is that there is simply something faulty about the board in question and attempts at pinpointing what it is were not really successful. After acquiring exactly the same board from a different vendor (which was also of visibly better quality), all of my tests/software worked smoothly from the get-go, and none of the issues I described above ever appeared, so it seems like there was something wrong with the hardware of the original board.

Answer (score 0):

In a project at work we have spent many person-months porting and re-testing an already working esp8266 project from the non-RTOS SDK to the RTOS one solely because the old SDK does not support the latest cryptographic features.

I don't know if the exact feature you want is available in the old SDK, but it might simply be infeasible.

When we wanted to disable TKIP in the RTOS-SDK we were advised by Espresif to edit a file in the SDK:

In the file [`components/wpa_supplicant/src/esp_supplicant/esp_hostap.c`](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/blob/master/components/wpa_supplicant/src/esp_supplicant/esp_hostap.c), in the function `hostap_init`, change the lines:

```
auth_conf->wpa_group = WPA_CIPHER_TKIP;
auth_conf->wpa_pairwise = WPA_CIPHER_CCMP | WPA_CIPHER_TKIP;
auth_conf->rsn_pairwise = WPA_CIPHER_CCMP | WPA_CIPHER_TKIP;
```

to whatever ciphers you want.  We have:

```
 auth_conf->wpa_group = WPA_CIPHER_CCMP;
 auth_conf->wpa_pairwise = WPA_CIPHER_CCMP;
 auth_conf->rsn_pairwise = WPA_CIPHER_CCMP;
```

Hopefully you can see enough in the source code of the RTOS-SDK to understand what the various options could be, and then you can look in the source code of the SDK you are using to find something which looks equivalent (but sadly it might not be there).

Comment: I see, that is helpful information Tom, TY! The source code for the NON-OS SDK is simply not provided as far as I can tell. I can only find the headers and libraries for it on Espressif's GitHub, so editing the source is not an option...
But I am still mystified by one thing, and correct me if my reasoning is flawed. So, when building a project, I also build and link the Arduino core of which I only have 1 copy (in the Arduino IDE directory). The Arduino core utilizes and links the non-OS libraries which are stored at the same location, and of which there are also 1 copy...

Comment: ...How is it possible, that when I upload the same code to 2 different boards, I get 2 different behaviors?! The code is exactly the same, isn't it?

Comment: Good question! There can be a key stored in the NVM and maybe it is re-using that.  Try a full erase and reprogram everything.  I don't know much about what Arduino puts on top of the SDK, so maybe try using the tools from the SDK to make sure you have erased everything.

Comment: It's got to be something really vague and weird, definitely :D. Could you please clarify what NVM stands for?

Comment: non-volatile memory.  It's a part of the flash storage that is reserved for settings that persist when when powered off or when the program is updated.

Comment: OK, I see, thanks! Will keep that in mind jic, but some more tinkering today has revealed even stranger behavior that seems to exclude the nvm theory. I'll describe this in an edit to the question...